# how to access properties from inside a model rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, models

so i have a model named item that has a column named price. I assumed that columns would be stored as instance variables inside models but the method

```
 def price
   @price
 end
```

returns nothing. so my question is how do i access price from inside the model?

**extra info**
my reason for doing this is items sometimes have specials so i want a method *price* that checks for specials and changes the price if a special is active and leaves it alone if not, something like

```
 def price
   check_for_special
   @price
 end
```

Comment: Please edit your original question, not create a new one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActiveRecord automatically generates the setter and getter methods associated with a database field. `price` will be the getter method for the field of the same name.

By adding a `price` method you have overwritten the method created by ActiveRecord. As you are overwritting an existing method, you can access the original method by calling `super`. So you could to this:

```
def price
  check_for_special
  super
end
```

However, I'd not recommend doing that, as you usually need a method of just getting the price value, without it always calling another method. So

```
def price_with_check
  check_for_special
  price
end
```